# Service Fabric ServicePartitionResolver ResolveAsync

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am currently using the ServicePartitionResolver to get the http endpoint of another application within my cluster.

```
var resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();
var partition = await resolver.ResolveAsync(serviceUri, partitionKey ?? ServicePartitionKey.Singleton, CancellationToken.None);
var endpoints = JObject.Parse(partition.GetEndpoint().Address)["Endpoints"];
return endpoints[endpointName].ToString().TrimEnd('/');
```

This works as expected, however if I redeploy my target application and its port changes on my local dev box, the source application still returns the old endpoint (which is now invalid). Is there a cache somewhere that I can clear? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are cached. If you know that the partition is no longer valid, or if you receive an error, you can call the `resolver.ResolveAsync()` that has an overload that takes the earlier `ResolvedServicePartition` `previousRsp`, which triggers a refresh.

> This api-overload is used in cases where the client knows that the
>   resolved service partition that it has is no longer valid.

See this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication.md) too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are cached. There are 2 solutions to overcome this.

1. The simplest code change that you need to do is replace `var resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();` with `var resolver = new ServicePartitionResolver();`. This forces the service to create a new `ServicePartitionResolver` object to every time. Whereas, `GetDefault()` gets the cached object.
2. [Recommended] The right way of handling this is to implement a custom `CommunicationClientFactory` that implements `CommunicationClientFactoryBase`. And then initialize a `ServicePartitionClient` and call `InvokeWithRetryAsync`. It is documented clearly in [Service Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication) in the **Communication clients and factories** section.